# Permanent continuous replication with CouchDB across reboots

Tags: couchdb, replication, startup

How can I set up continuous replication after reboot? Continuous replication works only until the next reboot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you still need to trigger the continuous replication after a server restart.

However, I asked this question on IRC, and it turns out that v1.1 of CouchDB will most likely include a special database called `_replicator` that will store replication settings. That way, they will remain even after a server restart.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pain. But that feature in 1.1 is going to be killer!

Answer (score 8):

Continuous replication was not postponed to 1.3, it is available as of 1.1. As Dominic said, you use the _replicator database. Stick a doc in there like:

```
{
    "_id": "my_rep",
    "source":  "http://myserver.com:5984/foo",
    "target":  "bar",
    "create_target":  true,
    "continuous": true
}
```

For detailed documentation look here: https://gist.github.com/832610

Answer (score 2):

it seems they postponed it to 1.3 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-776